# How to display a flash message after multiple redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, flash-message

So I'm trying to display a flash after multiple redirects, but I can't get it to "keep"!  I tested out the code in my view file, and that's solid. What am I missing?

```
if response["status"] == "NotProcessed"
  redirect_to root_path, alert: "Does this work?"
```

That takes me back tot he root path, but no flash is displayed, so I added
flash.keep, and still nothing.
I even added:

```
      def redirect_to(*args)
        flash.keep
        super
      end
```

to my application controller... but nothing!

Thanks!

Comment: flash.keep never worked for me neither. i reassigned the flash[:key]  in my second redirect. that worked for me

Comment: Interesting.  Would you mind elaborating a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I had set `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in my ApplicationController, thus it removed the flash with each session.  I removed that and it works fine.

I must have inserted that early on in the application when dealing with a weather API.